# Ensure image in HTML email is considered safe by Apple

Tags: html, image, email, html-email

We are sending bulk emails through a 3rd party provider and any template that has an `<img>` element in it is being bounced back by Apple (to me.com and icloud.com addresses)

Through a process of elimination, we have determined the element is causing the bounce

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEU....C" alt="Your image" style="display: block;" border="0" />
```

Is there anything we can do with attributes to make the Apple servers trust the image? All other providers are letting the email through with no bounce

Comment: Normally you upload the image to a public server and load it in via https:. Is there any reason you've chosen to embed it?

Comment: Thanks @Nathan - I suggested this to the client but they are adamant they want it embedded for some reason so nothing I have control over.

Comment: I'm guessing, but, you can hide stuff in embedded images. So it's been flagged as potential spam. It's not normal. If that's the case, and from your process it seems like it is, then you have a case for the client to say that they'll have to accept not being able to send to 50%+ of their customers.